# Set env varibale before run npm command

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I have an npm command with a dynamical env variable:

```
"migration:create": "npx typeorm migration:create ./src/shared/dal/migrations/$npm_config_name"
```

Is there any chance to setup a popup which asks me to set this env variable `$npm_config_name` before running this script in PhpStorm?

I know it is possible by modifying the Run Configuration. But this is too inconvenient when before each run I need a new value for the variable and I have to modify the Run Configuration and set it there.

Comment: 2 ideas: 1) If the list of values is rather limited -- make a copy of this Run Configuration that will have a specific value and choose the right Run Config each time. 2) There is "Show this page" option on Run Configuration, it forces the IDE to show the Edit Run/Debug Configuration screen so you can adjust it (enter the desired value) before actually running it. I'm not aware of any "popups" that would ask for such a stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $Prompt$ macro to get a prompt on each run.

[image: Run configuration]

[image: Prompt]